# what to do if i need to get reply from gmail to my php website?

Tags: php, gmail

I am sending an e-mail to Gmail using the `php` `mail()` function.

I want to know what will happen when some one replies to a `php` web mail from `Gmail`?

How can i get the reply mail from Gmail, if reply was sent to that web mail?

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189802/can-i-use-gmail-as-smtp-server-for-my-website

Comment: You need a mail delivery agent setup for that mail address, you can't do that directly in PHP.

Comment: what i need to do for that

Answer (score 0):

You will need a mail service like Mailgun or Mandrill to receive the emails. I will also highly recommend you send email through a mail service. This will help the mails not ending up in spam etc.

I recommend Mailgun since they have a very well documented docs. You can see more here about receiving https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html#how-to-start-receiving-inbound-email